# SSH connection for existing EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm trying to get a ssh connection to a project I took over from a client. I created a new key using AWS cli: `aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name NewKeyName --query 'KeyMaterial' --output text > NewKeyName.pem` 
I changed the permission to 004. I see the key under "Key Pairs" in the AWS console webpage. I created a IAM user and granted it all permissions.

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/NewKeyName.pem rt@ec1-1-1-1.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com` `Permission denied (publickey)` .. I also tried with the regular public ip address.. I tried connecting with "EC2 Instance Connect" under "Instances > Connect to instance" and getting error: `Failed to connect to your instance Error establishing SSH connection to your instance. Try again later.` I tried connecting with "EC2 serial console" from "Instances > Connect to instance" and getting same error. I have no idea what else to try now... nothing seems to work.. I also tried creating my own private/public keys and uploading but same result.
I can see the key that was used to create the instance, but that user is gone, but we are supposed to be able to connect with a new ssh key right?

What more is there to try?

Answer (score 1):

[Changing an EC2 instance's SSH key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-key-pair.html) isn't possible without accessing the instance, either using the previous key or with a username/password previously set up directly on the instance.

IAM doesn't handle low-level user management within an instance.

If you can't recover the previous SSH key, the only way to access the data on that machine is to attach its volume to a newly created instance, which has a known SSH key associated with it.

Comment: I know I cannot change the one it was instanciated with, but as i mentioned I shold be able to add a new key-pair: https://linux.how2shout.com/add-a-new-key-pair-to-your-exisitng-aws-ec2-instances/

Comment: The step 5 in that link is "connect to EC2 instance", but in your situation you cannot connect without the old key pair.

Answer (score 0):

Want i did to fix this realizing that we do actually need to replace/add the ssh key in .ssh/authorized_keys before we are able to connect.

What I did was:

- detach the disk from aws console.
- create new linux instance with new disk and newly generated keys
- attach old disk to new instance (you now have 2 disks attached)
- ssh into new instance and mount the old disk
- cd into the mounted disk and change the .ssh/authorized_keys with the new key
- detach old disk and reattach to old instance which now that the updated authorized_keys file